How do I add a prefetch (or similar) to a django queryset, using contents of a JSONField?
Background
I have a complex analytics application using conventional relational setup where different entities are updated using a CRUD model.
However, our system is quite event driven, and it's becoming a real misery to manage history, and apply data migrations respecting that history.
So we're moving toward a quasi-noSQL approach in which I'm using JSON to represent data with a linked list of patches representing the history.
As far as data structure goes it's a very elegant solution and will work well with other services. As far as django goes, I'm now struggling to use the ORM.
My database is PostgreSQL.
Situation
Previously I had something like (pseudocode):
class Environment(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

class Analysis(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTime(auto_now_add=True)
    environment = models.ForeignKey(
        "myapp.Environment",
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name="analyses",
    )
    everything_else = models.JSONField()

Whereas I now will have:
class Environment(models.Model):  
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)  
  
class Analysis(models.Model):  
    created = models.DateTime(auto_now_add=True)
    everything = models.JSONField()

Where everything might be a JSON object looking like...
{
  "environment": "2bf94e55-7b47-41ad-b81a-6cce59762160",
  "other_stuff": "lots of stuff"
}

Now, I can still totally get the Environment for a given Analysis because I have its ID, but if I do something like this (again pseudocode):
for analysis in Analysis.objects.filter(created=today).all():
   print(Environment.objects.get(id=analysis.everything['environment'])

I of course get an N+1 error because I'm querying the database for the environment on every iteration.
In a simple script I could put all the ids in a list then do a single query for them all using ids__in filtering... but that doesn't work well with the django ecosystem, which typically relies on a get_queryset method to customise what gets fetched... In particular this will enable the solution to work with

API serialisers
admin methods.

Question
Given a queryset like Analysis.objects.filter(created=today).all(), how can I adjust this queryset to pre-fetch the related environment objects, now that their IDs are in a JSONField?

Please don't use JSON blobs: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/non-atomic-jsonfield-s.html

Never use JSON fields unless you absolutely can justify it.
JSON fields are a crutch that people lean on because they can't be bothered to design proper modeling.

Denormalise your json data into separate tables.
Use django history/some other built in/3rd party tools for historical tracking.

Json fields will obfuscate your logic and make everything un-workable. It's the second time I'm working on a project where engineers though it was elegant or easy and ended up paying half a years worth of time or more to fix the spaghetti caused by these.
As far as your prefetching stuff, you can use annotations & sub-queries, however anything you try to do with json fields will be expensive. Specifically because you can no longer take advantage of database operations such as joins/indexed lookups etc...
So how would I proceed in your situation:
If a problem is too complicated for the current use of JSON fields, but you still need to rely on them:
Use a post_save signal to populate a table that you maintain, representative of a segment of the json field that you need.
You can then use that table in your prefetch/ORM operation instead.

Thanks, but not an answer to the question. I already have denormalised data and am using django history. Also, this is one step in a wider transition. Very experienced data engineer here with a clear use case for this!

@thclark: but you say you denormalized data, so then you wrote a some sort of model where you can do the JOINing?

See my comment on how to proceed when you need to use JSON fields then, Just populate a table with what you need on post_save/on transaction complete. that will avoid having to sub-query over the json field. Unfortunatly the only other way would be to write some custom SQL to extract the values you need as arrays within json fields are not supported by orm lookups

@willeM_VanOnsem sorry I meant normalized. And I still have normalized data, it's just that now the relation is no longer a foreign key.

@thclark: the data can not be normalized if you have a JSON blob that is not "atomic", so if it is a composite, this essentially breaks 1NF.
